# I get a fail on selenium clicking a circle element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

When I am running the a test I am trying to click a element type=circle.
and is show me the follow error any help?

Jun 27, 2018 2:06:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions moveToElement
INFO: When using the W3C Action commands, offsets are from the center of element.
example:

```
<circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
```

Code for clicking the element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[@id='circle'")); 
Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: You have the code that executes your click as well?

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(
      By.xpath("//*[@id='circle'"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Comment: I might say that the issue is the moveToElement

Comment: AFAIK, `circle` tag is from the `svg` namespace, so try dealing with `svg` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click usign Java script Executor,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();","Target Webelement");
```